# Bitset in C++, about continuously add

Tags: c++, bitset

I want to add 1 value to the bitset until it over flows, I am wondering how to do this, like:

bitset<20> foo;   (foo=00000 00000 00000 00000)
how can we implement this function, continuously add one

> 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 > 00000 00000 00000 00000 00001 > 00000 00000 00000 00000 >00010 > 00000 00000 00000 00000 000011  until it overflows?

I am thinking about two ways;

```
foo.to_ulong();
```

how to convert unsigned long back to bitset again? C++ documentation indicates it is possible, but in the library, I can only see bitset (unsigned long val), which is creating a new bitset

2.
somehow bit operations, both got stuck, help needed

Comment: There is no way to make a bitset 'overflow'

Comment: @DieterLücking I guess OP means to treat a bitset as a binary representation of an arbitrary but fixed size integer.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following: http://ideone.com/C8O8Qe

```
template <std::size_t N>
bool increase(std::bitset<N>& bs)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != bs.size(); ++i) {
        if (bs.flip(i).test(i) == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; // overflow
}
```

And then to iterate on all values :

```
std::bitset<20> bs;

do {
    std::cout << bs << std::endl;
} while (increase(bs));
```

Comment: this won't work, the time of looping is just size_t, I want to add one each time, which indicates a complexity 2 to the power size_t

Comment: I like the tersness of the inner condition. But why compare to true? Otherwise I'd bump this ;-)

Comment: @javarookie Your complexity "analysis" is quite off the mark. The effort for adding 1 is O(n/2) where n = bitset.size(). You can't get any better than this because a conversion to int will take just as long. - And: write a program computing 2^n and look at what you wrote...

Comment: @laune: I prefer to be explicit, but you are right, `== true` can be omitted.

Comment: @laune: about complexity, OP wanted to see the loop which call `increase` (which wasn't in my initial answer (but was in live example)).

Comment: @Jarod42 Then the complexity is O(n^2), which is still far from O(2^n)

Comment: @laune: OP wants to count from `0` to `2^n` (with `n == 20` in his example)

Comment: @laune, Sorry guys for misunderstanding, what I want to do is add one to bitset each time, then count up to 2^n, not make the add function a complexity of 2^n. thank you guys, though, i had figured out neither of them yet.

Comment: qJarod42 OK, of course, repeating the increment many (x) times will increase the complexity to x times the complexity for a single increment. So, if the complexity of a single increment is O(n/2), you'll have to mulitply as many times as you do the increment, which will be 2^n times O(n/2). But I'd not call this the "complexity of the algorithm", by the same reasoning as counting up to N = 2^n is not said to have a complexity of O(2^n). If the task is to generate all bit strings from 000...0 to 111...1 for some length n, you could claim that this has O(n.2^n).

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help you:

```
bitset<20> b;

bool overflow = false;
while( ! overflow ){
    cout << b << endl; // prints bits in reversed order
    int ipos = b.size();
    overflow = true;
    while( overflow && --ipos >= 0 ){ 
        overflow = b[ipos];
        b[ipos] = ! b[ipos];
    }
}
```

tested by @Jarod42, thanks.

Comment: But it does produce the sequence of values you asked for. Insert a printout of the bitset just before the final closing brace.

Comment: @javarookie You cannot "add" to a bit anyway. The flip is the simplification of the logic that determines the value of the current bit in an adder if the carry is 1 and the other operand is 0. The carry is the old value.

Comment: @Jarod42 +1, and the bit order is a matter of definition. Might run the loop from 0 to size()-1 - whatever.

Comment: @laune  sorry, lane, my fault. now it's my time to really look into the code, why in first place I just did not get it. really sorry